# Mac keeps creashing with kernel panic

Tags: mojave, crash, kernel-panic

For the last week or so my Mac has been randomly kernel panicking. 
My usage of the my laptop has not changed, so I have no idea why this started all of a sudden. 
This is a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports) running Mojave 10.14.3

The error message/panic report I get is:

```
    Mon Feb 18 16:58:54 2019

    Anonymous UUID:       180C0C23-1428-3DAC-4800-C7DB11C29C57

Wed Feb 20 07:44:22 2019

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800a8da29d): Kernel trap at 0xffffff800a855930, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00007fb11b703020, CR3: 0x0000000456387069, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000002, RBX: 0xffffff803b64e088, RCX: 0xffffff8041326f00, RDX: 0xffffff921d293cc0
RSP: 0xffffff921d293c20, RBP: 0xffffff921d293ca0, RSI: 0xffffff921d293cb8, RDI: 0x0000000000000000
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff800b09e7f0, R11: 0xffffff921d293da8
R12: 0x0000000000000102, R13: 0xffdfff80413233c0, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010293, RIP: 0xffffff800a855930, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00007fb11b703020, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x0, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff800a54c290 : 0xffffff800a7aeb0d 
0xffffff800a54c2e0 : 0xffffff800a8e8653 
0xffffff800a54c320 : 0xffffff800a8da07a 
0xffffff800a54c390 : 0xffffff800a75bca0 
0xffffff800a54c3b0 : 0xffffff800a7ae527 
0xffffff800a54c4d0 : 0xffffff800a7ae373 
0xffffff800a54c540 : 0xffffff800a8da29d 
0xffffff800a54c6b0 : 0xffffff800a75bca0 
0xffffff800a54c6d0 : 0xffffff800a855930 
0xffffff921d293ca0 : 0xffffff800a7dd459 
0xffffff921d293d20 : 0xffffff800a7dd942 
0xffffff921d293d50 : 0xffffff800a81c22f 
0xffffff921d293d80 : 0xffffff800a7b43ed 
0xffffff921d293dd0 : 0xffffff800a78ebe5 
0xffffff921d293e50 : 0xffffff800a7a35ae 
0xffffff921d293ef0 : 0xffffff800a8c17bb 
0xffffff921d293fa0 : 0xffffff800a75c486 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: sysmond

Mac OS version:
18D109

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Thu Dec 20 20:46:53 PST 2018; root:xnu-4903.241.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1970B070-E53F-3178-83F3-1B95FA340695
Kernel slide:     0x000000000a400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800a600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800a500000
System model name: MacBookPro14,2 (Mac-CAD6701F7CEA0921)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2416694242315
last loaded kext at 2126281835364: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8df83000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 2347065417594: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio 315.6 (addr 0xffffff7f8df0b000, size 413696)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.2.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.3.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.fileutil  18.306.12
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.46
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.10
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.28.4
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.10f1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics  12.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsFramebuffer   12.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.11
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.6
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.241.4
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 138.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   190
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    527
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.28.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 710.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   700.7
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  6.0.10f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.10f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.10
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.10
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.14
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    2410.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 138.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.10f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.10f1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  2410.5
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    2410.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    55
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  55
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.230.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.200.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.200.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    700.7
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro14,2, BootROM 184.0.0.0.0, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 3.1 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.44f1
Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650, Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4B3445424533303445422D45474347202020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x171), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.2)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.10f1, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: USB 10/100/1000 LAN, Ethernet, en7
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: iBridge
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 39.2
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 39.2
```

I ran the hardware diagnostic (Hold D on restart) and it found no issues

Comment: I would start by trying to boot into Safe (hold Shift) and/or Recovery Mode (Cmd-R).  See if it happens in either of those environments.  Then let's proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as a kernel panic is mainly caused by third party kernel extensions and you seem to have `com.joshuawise.kexts.HoRNDIS` which is for android tethering, I would suggest you start in recovery mode and disable that one. You will need to install the latest version of that if you use it, I guess.

How did I find out ? In kernel panic messages, all kext (kernel extensions, drivers) are listed. I looked for non-Apple extensions and you seem to have 3:

```
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.2.1 <---OK, intel should be fine
com.nvidia.CUDA 1.1.0             <---OK, NVidia should be fine
com.joshuawise.kexts.HoRNDIS    6
```

Comment: I was about to accept this as solution because I hadn't crashed all day after removing (both) HoRNDIS and CUDA, but then I crashed as I was about to click the check :/

I've updated the panic report.

Answer (score 1):

You stated that your laptop started to do this randomly as of late?

Was it after you upgraded to Mojave? Did you recently spill anything on the computer? Or was it dropped in any way?

What kind of peripherals do you have connected to the Mac? Did you change anything inside the Mac?

Is your computer overheating? Are you running a lot of labor intensive read/write operations?

Also take a look at this line in your report:

> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: sysmond

This is telling you that the sysmond service was the last thing running before it went into kernel panic. This is the system monitor daemon. It probably is hogging up a lot of CPU, which has been known to happen in older OS's. It's possible that is the source of your issue.

I would check for the more obvious signs first like the ones I stated, and then if it comes down to it, do the following:

- First do an NVRAM reset
- If above didn't work, do a clean Mojave install.
- If that doesn't work either, take to Apple.

You might have nothing connected to the computer, and there is no third party kernel extension running, so this could point to a hardware issue, and might need to be taken back to Apple.